# Issue freezing the parent window of a webpage (opened window doesn't load in Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to make our webpages work in Chrome, as they currently work in IE. We noticed opening new windows using window.open() works fine in Internet Explorer but not Chrome (I asked another question about this earlier but failed to provide a minimum reproducible example so there was trouble). In my attempt to create a reproducible example, I noticed that the issue was not in the window.open() but rather the way that we were freezing our parent screen while the new window was up. This method of looping the main window while the new window is not closed works great in Internet Explorer, but in Chrome, the new window fails to load and appears as about.blank. Is there a better way to do this in Chrome?

EDIT A comment suggested to look at event listeners. I have been looking considerably into them, and I can't find anything relating to my issue. The listener seems to just call a function when a certain thing (loading the page) happens. So I can assume that I can use the listener to call a function that will freeze the main page, but it seems that no such function exists. Is there such a function or way to do this that I am missing?

Below is what I hope to be a sufficient minimum reproducible example. If I am missing any other information that you need in order to answer this question, please let me know. Any guidance is appreciated, thank you!

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function EnterAudit() {
        var sObj = window.open("windowOpenMinReprodExample.asp", "", "width=650px, height=700px");
        Bounce(sObj);

        //wait for window to close
        while (!(sObj.closed)) { }
        document.myform.submit();
        return;
    }

    function Bounce(w) {
        window.blur();
        w.focus();
    }
</script>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="EwayAudit.asp" method="post" id="myform">

<input type="button" tabindex="2" id="Submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="EnterAudit();"/>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: while loop is not allowing it to update..... attach an onload listener

Comment: Could you explain further? I'm not familiar with an onload listener, I don't believe we use it in any of our webpages that I've seen. These work on Internet Explorer and I believe this one in particular worked fine on Edge too.

Comment: Search "[Javascript] window.open detect onload" I am sure you will get answers here.

Comment: Oh sorry I said the above example works on Edge, I was mistaken, but it does work on IE.

Comment: @epascarello I have been looking considerably into the event listeners, and I can't find anything relating to my issue. The listener seems to just call a function when a certain thing (loading the page) happens. So I can assume that I can use the listener to call a function that will freeze the main page, but it seems that no such function exists.

Comment: So yo ubind an event listener to the window you just created. When that fires you call the code that submits the form....